# Need to know Gear/Hour meaning in pricinng section of Openshift

Tags: openshift

I am a newbie of OpenShift PaaS plate form. I am still evaluating OpenShift and planning to upgrade to "Bronze Plan" but first I want to understand what is meaning of "gear/hour" in the pricing section? How the billing amount will be calculated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will be charged the gear price for each size gear for each hour that you have that gear running.  For instance:

If you were to run a small gear for 1 month (which is about 750 hours), it would cost you about $15.

Running a medium gear for 1 month (about 750 hours) would cost about $37.50
Running a large gear for 1 month (about 750 hours) would cost about $75.00

So for each gear that you are running, we charge you that price per hour.  If you are running a scaled application, you are charged for each database gear that runs, and each web/haproxy gear that is running.  You can email openshift@redhat.com if you have more specific questions.

Comment: just to be clear, according to https://www.openshift.com/products/pricing that cost is only if we go over the three free small gears, correct? so if we run just 1-3 small gears it's still $0/month?

Comment: Just a warning, you will **still be charged** for gears that are "stopped". I guess they still consider them "running" because they are using up space or something.

Comment: @Luc - That is standard practice across the industry to charge for "stopped" gears, as the resources are still reserved for your use at any time.

Comment: @TobyJ On https://www.openshift.com/products/pricing#free is written * "All plans include 3 small basic gears for free". So it should be $0/month for the three small gears.